# socket.io : Receiving data from server node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

i created a node js server that emit data to html client using socket.io :

```
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var child = spawn('node', ['file.js']);

child.stdin.write("Hello there!");

child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('We received a reply: ' + data);
    var listener = io.listen(server);
listener.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
     setTimeout(function(){
        socket.emit('imageFromBlob', {'imageFromBlob': data});
    }, 3000);
});

});
// Listen for any errors:
child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('There was an error: ' + data);
});

server.listen(8001);
```

The data that i want to send to the client is a base 64 data, but when i run my server js, i'm getting in the browser : [object ArrayBuffer] but i want to get my data as is displayed when i do console.log(data).

how can i extract the data as displayed when running my server from this ArrayBuffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is `data.toString()`